# Exporting Collection of Hashtable data to CSV

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am trying to export to CSV the name/value pairs of a collection hashtable items.  The I have not found the correct syntax for the select-object portion of the code. I would the CSV file to have columes for Url and Owner.  Thanks for the help

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$collection = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
$SiteInfo = @{};

$SiteInfo.Url = "http://some.url.com";
$SiteInfo.Owner = "Joe Smith";
$collection.Add($SiteInfo);

$SiteInfo.Url = "http://another.url.com";
$SiteInfo.Owner = "Sally Jones";
$collection.Add($SiteInfo);


$collection | foreach{
    $hashTableDate = $_;
    $hashTableDate | Select-Object -Property Url, Owner;
}| Export-Csv  "C:\UsageReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter '|'

# results: file is empty :(
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Convert to PSObject and then export to CSV

All that "foreach" stuff is not necessary.  Just convert your hash to PSObject then export!

This example uses an [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist) to store the HashTables and then exports that ArrayList to CSV.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$collection = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)

$SiteInfo = @{}
$SiteInfo.Url = "http://some.url.com"
$SiteInfo.Owner = "Joe Smith"
$collection.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $SiteInfo)) | Out-Null

$SiteInfo = @{}
$SiteInfo.Url = "http://another.url.com"
$SiteInfo.Owner = "Sally Jones"
$collection.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $SiteInfo)) | Out-Null


$collection | Export-Csv  "UsageReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter '|'
```

#### Things that won't work.

Note that while this here works:

```
$collection.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $SiteInfo))
```

... here are some things that will NOT work:

- Leaving out one set of parenthesis will NOT work:

  ```
  $collection.Add(New-Object PSObject -Property $SiteInfo)
  ```
- Leaving out the `-property` argument label will NOT work:

  ```
  $collection.Add((New-Object PSObject $SiteInfo))
  ```
- Just using `+=` will NOT work:

  ```
  $collection += $SiteInfo
  ```

For these you will get error messages and/or weird entries in the CSV file.

#### Why "Out-Null"?

Additional note: [`$collection.Add()` outputs the index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add) of the highest valid index when you run it. The `| Out-Null` just throws away that number if you don't want it.