# Exporting Hashtable to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, hashtable

I'm trying to write a Powershell script which will take a several very long space-separated files and export some columns to similarly-named CSV files.

I do have a successful version:

```
Foreach ($file in $files) {
    $WriteString=""
    $outfile = $path + "\" + ($file -replace ".{4}$") + ".csv"  

    Get-Content -Path $path"\"$file | Select-Object -Skip $lines | ForEach-Object{
        $ValueArray = ($_ -split "\s+")
        $WriteString += $ValueArray[1] + "," + $ValueArray[2] + "," + $ValueArray[3] + "`n"
    } 

    Add-Content -Path $outfile -Value $Writestring
 }
```

This works, but is extremely slow - it takes over 16 hours for the script to fully run. The main cause (I think) is adding to the string. I've tried improving this using a hashtable:

```
Foreach ($file in $files) {
    $outfile = $path + "\" + ($file -replace ".{4}$") + ".csv"

    $ParseLines = Get-Content -Path $path"\"$file | Select-Object -Skip $lines 

    $OutputData = ForEach ($Line in $ParseLines) {
        $ValueArray = ($Line -split "\s+")
        $Line | Select-Object $ValueArray[1], $ValueArray[2], $ValueArray[3]
    } 

   $OutputData | Export-CSV -Path $outfile #-NoTypeInformation
 }
```

However, this is only exporting one line of the hashtable:

```
#TYPE Selected.System.String
"636050.000","7429825.000","77.438"
,,
,,
,,
,,
,,
,,
```

If I change the last line to:

```
Set-Content -Path $outfile -Value $OutputData
```

then the output becomes:

```
@{636050.000=; 7429825.000=; 77.438=}
@{636075.000=; 7429825.000=; 75.476=}
@{636100.000=; 7429825.000=; 74.374=}
@{636125.000=; 7429825.000=; 73.087=}
@{636150.000=; 7429825.000=; 71.783=}
@{636175.000=; 7429825.000=; 70.472=}
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong with either the hashtable or Export-CSV, but I can't figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

As requested below, here's part of one source file. I cut out all non-data rows, and don't include headers in my output CSV, as the input program (that the CSV files go into) doesn't require them, and the outputs are self-evident (Not much chance of getting the X, Y and Z values wrong just by looking at the data).

```
*
* DEFINITION
*   HEADER_VARIABLES 3
*     QUALITIES        C  16   0 key
*     DATE             C  12   0
*     TIME             C  12   0
*   VARIABLES 4
*     X                F  12   3
*     Y                F  12   3
*     Z                F  12   3
*     gcmaq0.drg       F  12   3
*
*        1         2         3         4
*23456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678
*         X|          Y|          Z| gcmaq0.drg|
*
* HEADER:QUALITIES       29Aug2018   13:53:16    
  636575.000 7429800.000      75.551      75.551
  636600.000 7429800.000      77.358      77.358
  636625.000 7429800.000      78.823      78.823
  636650.000 7429800.000      80.333      80.333
  636675.000 7429800.000      82.264      82.264
  636700.000 7429800.000      84.573      84.573
  636725.000 7429800.000      87.447      87.447
```

Comment: Can you share (a part) of your input file (including the header) and add it to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid slow operations like appending to strings (or arrays) in a loop. Change this:

```cs
Get-Content -Path $path"\"$file |
    Select-Object -Skip $lines |
    ForEach-Object {
        $ValueArray = ($_ -split "\s+")
        $WriteString += $ValueArray[1] + "," + $ValueArray[2] + "," + $ValueArray[3] + "`n"
    }

Add-Content -Path $outfile -Value $Writestring
```

into this:

```
Get-Content -Path "${path}\${file}" |
    Select-Object -Skip $lines |
    ForEach-Object {
        ($_ -split "\s+")[1..3] -join ','
    } |
    Set-Content -Path $outfile
```

Replace `Set-Content` with `Add-Content` if you actually want to append to an existing file.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, it's extremely quick. However, the output is not in CSV format. It generates a single column of data. Do I need to concatenate the values back together similarly to my original script?

Comment: `($_ -split "\s+")[1..3] -join ","` in the `ForEach-Object`? You'll need to deal with headers separately, if they're not in the input files.

Comment: Perfect, that did it! The exact outputs I need, and with extremely fast speed. It looks like it's at least 12x faster than my original solution.

Comment: @gms0ulman The question didn't look like there were headers. At least none that were supposed to appear in the output file.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Fair enough - I do have a psobject bias when dealing with these questions.

Answer (score 1):

`Export-Csv` works with objects. It expects properties and values - what you're providing (judging from the `Set-Content` results) is hashtable with keys only.

One way around this is to create an object and increment values from each line.

```
Foreach ($file in $files) {

    $outfile    = $path + "\" + ($file -replace ".{4}$") + ".csv"
    $ParseLines = Get-Content -Path $path"\"$file | Select-Object -Skip $lines 

    ForEach ($Line in $ParseLines) {

        $ValueArray = ($Line -split "\s+")

        [array]$OutputData += [pscustomobject]@{
            header1 = $ValueArray[1]
            header2 = $ValueArray[2]
            header3 = $ValueArray[3]
        }

    } 

   $OutputData | Export-CSV -Path $outfile #-NoTypeInformation

}
```

Not sure if this is the optimal way if you have very large files - am sure a regex guru can come up with something more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - it works, which is great! Unfortunately, its speed is about the same as my original string-based solution.

Comment: I was afraid that'd be an issue with the files being large - worth knowing for smaller datasets though. [Ansgar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52087648/5039142) is the kind of regex guru solution I was hoping would be posted!

Answer (score 0):

The solution above by [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) worked best, but I also found a second way of doing it at [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407239/exporting-collection-of-hashtable-data-to-csv) It uses a ArrayList to store the hashtable, then writes the ArrayList. This method is almost, but not quite as fast as Ansgar's solution. (About 10x faster than string method, vs 12x for regex method)

```
Foreach ($file in $files) {
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$collection = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
    $outfile = $path + "\" + ($file -replace ".{4}$") + ".csv" 

    $ParseLines = Get-Content -Path $path"\"$file | Select-Object -Skip $lines 

    $OutputData =@{}
    ForEach ($Line in $ParseLines) {
        $ValueArray = ($Line -split "\s+")
        $OutputData.Easting = $ValueArray[1]
        $OutputData.Northing = $ValueArray[2]
        $OutputData.ZValue = $ValueArray[3]

        $collection.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property $OutputData)) | Out-Null
    } 

    $collection | Export-CSV -Path $outfile -NoTypeInformation
 }
```